# know the suggestion is opened

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, input

I have a html form with no submit button. I want to submit that form upon hitting ENTER button. I used a simple jquery code to submit the form upon hitting ENTER.

```
$("form :input").keypress(function(e)
{
    if(e.keyCode == 13)
    {
        $(this).parents('form').submit();
    }
});
```

But there is a problem with this code. When i type in text field and want to select a suggestion (these are the suggestions, suggested by browser based on the history for that field) for that field using "ENTER" key it trigger the submit of the current form. I want to skip this as well.

Is there something like in jquery or javascript

```
$("form :input").keypress(function(e)
{
    if(e.keyCode == 13)
    {
        if(! $(this).is('suggestOpened'))    // i want something like this
        {
             // submit the form
        }

    }
});
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can prevent the "default behaviour" of an event (submitting the form in your case): http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/

Comment: can you add your code on jsfiddle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there's no such event. You could play with `onchange` and `onblur` events to intercept whether the user is filling a particular field, but anyway without a submit button:

- There's no way for the user to figure-out how to submit the form
- The same action (enter key press) could lead to two different actions, which breaks UI consistency

IMHO you should definitely place a submit button.